# Fiddle leaf tree - is this root dead?

Tags: diagnosis, roots, ficus, rot, root-pruning

Please check images below. The fiddle leaf tree has been losing leaves, and they were brown at their endings. When the leaves fall, I noticed inside there is a brownish water.
Is it possible to save this plant, even if it means cutting the black part?
I don't know if it's black due to rotting or black just because it was in the soil. Many roots look brownish but also many are yellow.
Thank you.
[image]

[image]